# How to find the section header position when click on child?

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view with two sections one is header and other is child.so when click on child how can i get corresponding header position

Answer (score 0):

you can add a tag to child from parrent, e.g.:
textView is for example header and button1 is child when you click on child, parrent text is modified

```
  TextView textView = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textListView)).setText("some text");


Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(this);
button1.setTag(textView);
```

And in the onClickListener:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    TextView text = (TextView) v.getTag();
    text.setText("new text");
 }
```

Comment: I am using view holder is it work for it?and storing an view is good solution?